# How to remove formatting in a field after retrieve it from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am retreiving a field from a DB with pre formatted text in there. For example the text contains  
 etc. I would like to remove all the formats and just display the plain text. Just so I can read a quick preview of what is in the actual field. And the viewer can just click on the link attached to see the whole article where the formatted text is intact.

Display:    `<?php echo substr($row_RS_NEWS_B2['Article'], 0, 150); ?<a href="news.php?news_id=<?php echo $row_RS_NEWS_B2['id']; ?>-<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $row_RS_NEWS_B2['Title']); ?>">... Read More</a>`

Is this possible?
Any help welcome

Comment: tried `strip_tags`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, your solution is to use strip_tags() function for removing all the tags from your text. Am I getting your request right?

Comment: That done it. Thanks for that. I just didn't know what to use.